# Grunt stopped working all of a sudden

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

Tried running Grunt build and Grunt watch on my project yesterday and I ran into the follow error:

```
Fatal Error: Unable to find local grunt.
```

I made sure the files weren't deleted. I tried reinstalling Node and Grunt. Files are there and reinstalling didn't work. I've included the debug file for reference. Does anyone know what the issue could be?

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'E:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'E:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install' ]
2 info using npm@1.3.24
3 info using node@v0.10.25
4 verbose node symlink E:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
5 error install Couldn't read dependencies
6 error package.json ENOENT, open 'D:\sites\alleywire\package.json'
6 error package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
6 error package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.
7 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
8 error command "E:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "E:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
9 error cwd D:\sites\alleywire
10 error node -v v0.10.25
11 error npm -v 1.3.24
12 error path D:\sites\alleywire\package.json
13 error code ENOPACKAGEJSON
14 error errno 34
15 verbose exit [ 34, true ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install `grunt` locally with your project (install without `-g`). This is not the same as `grunt-cli` which is the grunt command on your command line.

Run `npm install` inside your project folder if you have a `package.json` file there.

Comment: Oh that worked. I know I installed it in another hard drive by mistake the first time but it was working. The paths were correct. You have any idea why they stopped functioning?